# From when and which perspective did Imam and Mu'addhin of Masjid start to get paid?

Tags: history

As far I know, in the age of Nabi (sm.), sahabi (ra.), tabeyin (rh.), tabe-tabeyin (rh.), there was no instance of paying Imam and Muajjin (Muadhin/Muezzin) of Masajid.

But now-a-days, we see, in almost every Masjid, there remains a paid Imam, a paid Muajjin, a paid Khadim and may be somebody else.

From when and which perspective Imam and Muajjin are started to get paid?

Comment: @Medi1Saif You are absolutely right. Jajakallah.

Comment: I think it's hard to say: Personally I don't know about a payed Muadhin and many Imams do this "job" as a part time job. That means they have been chosen either by the mosque visitors or government to lead the prayers and maybe get some kind of payment, but have a regular job or business. I only found quotes regulating this in books of ibn Khaldun, al-Ghazaly and al-Mawardy but most dislike a paid Imam. So paid Imams wouldn't be a normal case in a Muslim country.

Answer (score 0):

Getting paid for prayer is Haram. But there is no problem with paying for expenses such as taxis, etc. [Reference](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa1943)

When the directors of a Masjid cannot find a free Imam, so they have no way to find someone who is paid. Some Imams have no incoming job and are studying Islamic lessons in Hawza, which leaves them with little or no income to cover their living costs. Although true believers are always provided food and money [from where he does not reckon](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/65/3/). But such true believers are rare, like gemstones, and as the Quran said, ["and how few they are!".](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/38/24/)

About Khadim (servants) who work part-time or full-time, it is not Haram, and their rights should be considered, especially when there are laws for workers in that country.